# Load Google Chart API asynchronously

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-visualization

Is there a possibility to load Google Chart API asynchronously like Google Maps API? I've tried out two different things:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.google.com/jsapi');
```

and

```
$.getScript('http://www.google.com/jsapi');
```

both are not working.
Any suggestions?

Comment: "… are not working." What error message(s) do you get?

Comment: that is the problem, there is none! What Firebug reports is:  http://bit.ly/aYisn3

Answer (score 1):

Due to [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions you cannot perform AJAX requests to distant domains which explains why [`getJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getjson/) doesn't work. As far as [`getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) is concerned there [shouldn't be any problems](http://docs.jquery.com/Release%3ajQuery_1.2/Ajax#Cross-Domain_getScript).